# Get the current version and level of listitem

Tags: client-object-model, version-history

I'm using a client script to retrieve listitem from a context.
Everything works and load my item with and it's ok.

```
myCtxtWeb.Load(item);
myCtxtWeb.ExecuteQuery();
```

Now I'd like to know the versions and level, but these properties doesn't exist

Are there a way to get them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution found

```
    SP.File newsItemFile = targetItem.File;
SP.FileVersionCollection fileVersions = newsItemFile.Versions;
myCtxtWeb.Load(fileVersions);
myCtxtWeb.ExecuteQuery();
if (fileVersions.Count > 0)
{

    SP.FileVersion currentVer = fileVersions[fileVersions.Count - 1];//get current version
    if (currentVer.VersionLabel == "1.0")
    {
        return "add";
    } 
}
```

Hope it helps some people